# $a^n+ b^n$ is not a prime number when $n$ is not a power of $2$.

Tags: number-theory, analysis, prime-numbers, divisibility

Suppose $a, b$ and $n$ are positive integers, $a+b>2$, and $n$ is not a power of $2$. Prove that $a^n+ b^n$ is not a prime number.

Comment: `Since n is not a power of 2, we can assume n to be odd` No, think $\,6\,$ for example.

Comment: yes then how can I proceed with the proof?

Comment: You just need to modify your argument.  if $n=2^km$ with $m$ odd, then use your argument to show that $a^{2^k}+b^{2^k}$ divides $a^n+b^n$

Answer (score 4):

You can't "assume $n$ to be odd", but you can say that it has an odd factor $> 1$.

Comment: can you give some hints to prove it?

Comment: [Fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)

Answer (score 4):

You can not assume it's odd, but you can assume it contains an odd factor.

Consider $n=2^k\cdot x$ where $x$ is odd.

$$a^n+b^n=a^{2^k\cdot x}+b^{2^k\cdot x}=(a^{2^k}+b^{2^k})(a^{2^k\cdot(x-1)}-a^{2^k\cdot(x-2)}b^{2^k}+...-b^{2^k\cdot(x-2)}a^{2^k}+b^{2^k\cdot(x-1)})$$

Since both brackets are greater than $1$, $a^n+b^n$ is composite.

Comment: `Since both brackets are greater than 1` - how you can show the second part is $1$ ?

Comment: @taritgoswami since $x\ge3$    $a^n+b^n>a^{2^k}+b^{2^k}$